# User authentication using a certificate X.509 in Python with Flask on Windows 10

Tags: python, authentication, flask, ssl-certificate

I have written code that launches my server, which interacts with the user + created a CA that issued certificates for the server and client. I am planning to implement mutual authentication.

Can you help me with how to make the browser prompt the user for a certificate when accessing the page, similar to the image [Select a Sertificete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5toC.png). I have successfully imported the client certificate in the p12 format, and it is displayed in the Chrome certificate store. I have tested the certificate selection using this website https://server.cryptomix.com/secure.

If you can suggest other methods for authenticating users in the browser, I would be glad

I tried, but it didn't work:
request.environ.get('SSL_CLIENT_CERT'),
return {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Negotiate'},
Web Cryptography API on JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.load_cert_chain('cert.pem', 'key.pem')
context.load_verify_locations('CA_cert.pem')
context.options |= ssl.OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True, debug=True, ssl_context=context, port=443)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).